# Fabric.js magnifer not working while maintaing aspect ratio using canvas.centerObject

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am writing a magnifier in Fabric.js and it works fine without maintaining aspect ratio but it does not work if aspect ratio is maintained(lens is getting misplaced).

[Link to working magnifier in fabric.js without aspect ratio, works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/Lakkrkfv/5/)

[Link to magnifier in fabric.js with aspect ratio, doesn't work properly because lens is getting misplaced](https://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/Lakkrkfv/6/)

Code :
`//Please check fiddle`

Answer (score 0):

it just seems like you are not accounting for the left offset of the first image. I belive if you multiply the left offset by the scale it seems to work for me.

`lens.set('left', -(scale - 1) * x + (canvas.getObjects()[0].left * 2));`